# Append a string with quotes from PHP to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, css

i want to append a sting with quotes (eg. `< span class='MyClass'>` ) to some jQuery Elements, which are stored in a database. This snippet works as i want.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    <?php 
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT concat(year(`wann`), lpad(month(`wann`),2,0), lpad(day(`wann`),2,0)) as wann, `wieviel` FROM `zecken`");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        for($i=1; $i <= $row["wieviel"]; $i++) {
    ?>

$('#<?php echo $row["wann"]; ?>').append("<span class='descr bg-danger'>1</span>");

    <?php 
        } 
      } 
    ?>
  });
</script>
```

I just want to write in completely in PHP, and it also works if i delete the css-classes "descr bg-danger" from the span. Without css-classes my solution would be:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    <?php 
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT concat(year(`wann`), lpad(month(`wann`),2,0), lpad(day(`wann`),2,0)) as wann, `wieviel` FROM `zecken`");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        for($i=1; $i <= $row["wieviel"]; $i++) {

          // How to add a class to this appended span ?????
          echo "$('#".$row["wann"]."').append('<span >1</span>'); ";        
        } 
      } 
    ?>

  });
</script>
```

If i have to escape some quotes, how do i have to do this?
It's like i would need a third pair of different quotes for the span: ;)

```
echo "$('#".$row["wann"]."').append('<span class='''descr bg-danger'''>1</span>'); ";
```

Comment: To escape quotes you can use a backslash, such as: `.append('<span class=\"class-name\">');`

Comment: if concat soup isnt your style you also have [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) available to you. `sprintf('$("#%s").append("<span class=\"descr bg-danger\">1</span>")'), $row['wann']);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "$('#".$row["wann"]."').append('<span class=\\'descr bg-danger\\'>1</span>'); ";
```

or, as @Andi North mentioned:

```
echo "$('#".$row["wann"]."').append('<span class=\"descr bg-danger\">1</span>'); ";
```

(The difference between the two is that one outputs `class=\'...` and one outputs `class="...`. Either should be perfectly valid JavaScript.)